# What's the purpose of this red marking on the fuselage of a Boeing 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, aircraft-marking

I was watching some aircraft today and noticed a red marking on two of them.
[image: aa737]

[image: aa737ng]

What is that? I've seen that marking on many other aircraft.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Please go [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/boeing-737/synonyms) and suggest "737" as a synonym for that tag. It will link them together.

Comment: @TomMcW Can't do it because "737" does not have enough score.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@SMSvonderTann is correct. The marking is there for warning ground personnel about engine hazrd. In this photo (of a 737) you can see 'INGESTION HAZARD' written above the line.

[image: 737]

Image from airliners.net

In [this image](http://www.canstockphoto.com/737-ingestion-haz-0016343.html) it is possible to zoom in to see it much more clearly. Note that this marking is not found in all 737s. The danger area is marked with two lines- one in forward fuselage and another in the engine, as can be seen in @mins photo, which I've put below.

[image: B737]

Image from airlinereporter.com

Also, as @mins notes, the lines in 747 are for equipment positioning (to prevent damage to fairing, looks like)

Comment: as discussed in meta, please consider giving a useful source to the images: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2889/1467

Answer (score 3):

They are the markings for danger zone around the engines telling people to stay out of that area. If you notice, the engines also have that marking as well. They correspond to the side of the aircraft in the danger zone image:

[image]

Image from [boeing.com](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_3_08/article_04_3.html)

Comment: Danger when the engine is running? You can go back as far as the red line an not get sucked in? At what engine speed?

Comment: This answer establishes that the engines have reason for such a marking, but but establishes nothing regarding the forward fuselage.

Comment: DO YOU HAVE A SOURCE FOR THIS?  I ask because your track record for making things up that have absolutely no basis in reality is out there (metal rivets in a radome), and I fly these airplanes & have never seen any such marking as shown used for any such purpose as this. IS THIS YOUR OWN IDEA, OR CAN YOU SUPPORT IT?

Comment: @RalphJ I saw it on an older SE question that I can't find. If you so want it I can delete this until I find it.

Comment: [This Boeing article](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_3_08/article_04_1.html) (which incidentally appears to be where this answer's images were taken) gives a safety zone of up to a 14 ft radius from the center of the intake. The article also documents factory engine markings and suggested pavement safety zone markings. However, it gives no reference whatever to fuselage markings.

Comment: SMSvonderTann: to avoid future discussion about sources, it would be beneficial to provide the links to the pages from which you take the images, not generics "boeing.com". As the comment from @JonathanWalters shows.